# How to use v-for with vuex to render forms if I need v-bind?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuex

I have the following UI:

[image]

I will try to explain what is going on here. I have "Add message" button. When I click on the button I have new form with message: title, body, image, language (just multiple select via [this plugin](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/)). I have clicked twice - I have 2 messages. Simple.

I don't use vue router. Implementation of my routing is with the help of backend. It means that for each route I have new vuex state.

I'm going to keep my messages in vuex, but it's impossible to use `v-model` for this case. 
So, I will show my code.

store:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        messages: [],
       // more props are here ...
    },
    mutations: {
        setMessages(state, messages) {
            state.messages = messages;
        },
   // more setters are here
    },
    getters: {
        getMessages: state => {
            return state.messages;
        },
    // more getters are here 
    },
    actions: {
        updateMessagesAction: function({commit}, value) {
            console.log(value)
        },

    }
});
```

Messages component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" @click.prevent="createNewMessage">
            <i class="fa fa-language"/> Add message
        </button>

        <div>
            // now it works with local state, but I need to work with vuex
            <div v-for="(message, index) in messages">
                <button class="btn btm-sm btn-danger" @click="deleteMessage(index, message)"><i class="fa fa-remove"/>
                </button>

                <b-collapse collapsed :id="`collapse-${index}`">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="typo__label">Languages</label>
                            <multiselect
                                    v-model="message.languages"
                                    :options="getLanguagesOptions"
                                    :multiple="true"
                                    :close-on-select="true"
                                    :clear-on-select="false"
                                    :preserve-search="true"
                                    placeholder="Languages"
                                    label="name"
                                    track-by="id"
                            >
                            </multiselect>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title" class="typo__label">Title</label>

                            <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" ???  how to bind it to vuex ???? I dont understand :(((>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="text" class="typo__label">Body</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="text" ???  how to bind it to vuex ???? I dont understand :(((/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div id="upload-image">
                                <div v-if="!message.imageSrc">
                                    <h2>Image</h2>
                                    <input type="file" ref="file" @change="onFileChange($event, message)">
                                </div>
                                <div v-else>
                                    <img :src="message.imageSrc"/>
                                    <button @click.prevent="removeImage($event, message)">Remove</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr class="mb-2">
                    </form>
                </b-collapse>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    // imports

    export default {
        async created() {
            // set languages from servert to vuex
            let res = (await axios.post(this.urlForGettingLanguagesFromServerProp)).data;
            this.$store.commit('setLanguagesOptions', res);

        },
        name: "MessagesComponent",
        props: {
            urlForGettingLanguagesFromServerProp: String,
            uploadImageUrl: String,
            deleteImageUrl: String,
            selectedLanguagesIdsProp: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => []
            },
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapMutations(['setLanguagesSelected']),
            ...mapActions(['updateMessagesAction']),
            createNewMessage: function () {
                let message = {
                    languages: [],
                    languagesIds: [],
                    title: "",
                    text: "",
                    imageSrc: "",
                    imageDbId: 0
                };
                this.messages.push(message);
            },
            deleteMessage: function (index, message) {
                this.removeImage("", message);
                this.messages.splice(index, 1);
            },

            onFileChange: async function (e, message) {
              // this method add send image on server and save to state db image id ant path
            },
            removeImage: function (event, message) {
                // remove image from server
            }
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['getLanguagesOptions', 'getMessages'])
        },
        watch: {
            messages: {
                deep: true,
                immediate: true,
                handler(val, oldVal) {
                    let message = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val));
                    this.$store.commit("setMessages", message);

                }
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                messages: [],
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I call this component in a parent component. In the parent component I initiate vuex during update operation.

As you can see this component works with local state and synchronize local state with vuex. It's ok for Create operation. I can send messages to vuex, then I can take it in the parent component with other information and send it on the server. But what to do with Update? I have data from the server in the parent component but local state, of course, is empty for the Messages component. How to bind all messages to vuex and have ability to change each message separately? I mean, for example, to change title of the first message and to have it in vuex immediately? 
Please, help me improve this component.